# Redundant Apache RewriteRules, is there a way to shorten them?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I feel my Rewriterules are a bit redundant. Is there a way to shorten the following htaccess code,into *one line* please? I'm thinking it would use an * somewhere, but I just can't figure it out xD

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)?$ index.php?year=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?year=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ index.php?year=$1&month=$2[L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?year=$1&month=$2[L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ index.php?year=$1&month=$2&day=$3[L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?year=$1&month=$2&day=$3[L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ index.php?year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&post=$4[L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&post=$4[L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ index.php?year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&post=$4&action=$5 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&post=$4&action=$5 [L]
```

Thank you!

Currently, a php script checks if each GET parameter is set, and depending on which parameter is available, it does a different task. My PHP code works perfectly, no problem, but I am only wondering if there is a way to shorten the apache rules above. I also realize that this way of parsing GET parameters may create many many loopholes, so I appreciate any advice or feedback! :) Thanks a lot ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wanting everything to goto index.php?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule . index.php$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Oh this is cool, and then do I strtok the RequestURI to get the parameters I need? :) Thank you so much! ^_^

Comment: Works well, now I'm just gonna parse the url both ways, haha. Thanks again :)

Comment: Not a problem, I am glad it works for you. This explains a little further if you still need help.
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049